# Outputting linebreaks in javascript text output?

Tags: jquery, html, line-breaks

I am trying to output a scrolling series of text messages separated by linebreaks.

My code looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="xbMarquee.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
//set the marquee parameters
function init() { down_marquee.start(); }
var down_marquee_Text = '<em>"This is a test comment. - Love from Admin /n"This is a far longer test comment which is of greater and more powerful value to the research portions of both physical, mental and citrus flavoured sciences all around the world for years to come."-Love PICKLES"</em>';
var down_marquee_Direction = 'down';
var down_marquee_Contents='<span style="white-space:nowrap;">' + down_marquee_Text + '</span>';
up_marquee = new xbMarquee('down_marquee', '100%', '90%', 6, 100, down_marquee_Direction, 'scroll', down_marquee_Contents);
window.setTimeout( init, 200);
-->
</script></div>
```

Can anybody help me fix it so that the linebreak displays? I've tried everything I can think of including  tags and so on.

Thanks!

Nye

Comment: newline is represented as `\n` backslash n, not `/n`

Comment: Have just tried changing it, but still not working :(. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: Well that isn't how you print newlines in html in anycase, refer to Plynx answer, it was just something you should know either way.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `<pre>` HTML element which preserves whitespace. Otherwise replace `\n` with `<br>`.